# I just received an Announcer badge for a question I have no recollection of ever seeing before

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just received an Announcer badge for [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54525). As far as I can remember, I've never seen this question before. I certainly haven't shared it (I know nothing about this game, and it looks okay rule/meta wise, so I can't think of any reason why I would have needed to share a link). Yet the badge is in my list of accomplishments.

According to [this related meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7163/145980), one reason this might occur is due to user error - whoever *actually* posted a link mistyped my user ID instead of theirs. Though I guess it's possible, none of the users associated with that question (asker, answerers, and commenters) seem to have IDs close to mine, so I don't know if this is the case or not.

As much as I like shiny badges, I don't want to "steal" one from another person if that's what happened. Similarly, if the system glitched out, I don't want to have a cheated badge either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you *sure* you've never seen that question before? If it wasn't you, who wrote [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12357/153006)? ;)

In the following screenshot, the first link is the question you've "never seen before":

> [image]

It looks like you just forgot that you shared it. You can search a site for a part of a url with e.g. [`url:54525/145980`](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A54525%2F145980)

Comment: Looks like that's the culprit. I thought visits from SE sites don't count towards that badge, though? Does Meta not count?

Comment: @MageXy Due to the change to HTTPS, [it can't tell that the visits were from within SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345307/6083675). I like to think this is the new intended behavior :P

Comment: Neat! Guess I actually earned this badge. I will wear it with pride!